# React removes spacing between elements

Tags: html, reactjs

Here is a [fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/jsorensen/k84rqjbz/2/):

*html*

```html
<div>
  <button>One</button>
  <button>Two</button>
  <button>Three</button>
</div>
<div id="app"></div>
```

*js*

```html
function Buttons() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button>One</button>
      <button>Two</button>
      <button>Three</button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Buttons />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Basically whether or not I have any stylesheets, putting elements next to each other causes them to have 9px of space between them (at least on Chrome) but doing the exact same thing inside a react component puts no space between them. I would like to know why they are not consistent and how to make them consistent if possible.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the html output?  It sounds like either you have css and dont realize it or something is inserting &nbsp; into the output.

Comment: Just whitespaces. Declaring like `<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button>` inside your html won't cause any space. React is just trimming your jsx

Comment: So perplexing, and yet so obvious in retrospect! Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this difference is that React [removes whitespace at the beginning and ending of a line](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#string-literals-1).

The space you see between the buttons in your html example is due to the whitespace characters between the `<button>` tags in your html code.

If you change your React code to the following, you will get a result similar to your html example:

```js
function Buttons() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button>One</button> <button>Two</button> <button>Three</button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Buttons />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

My advice would be to let React remove the whitespace between the elements, and use css to properly control the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

> JSX removes whitespace at the beginning and ending of a line. It also removes blank lines. New lines adjacent to tags are removed; new lines that occur in the middle of string literals are condensed into a single space.

So the following declaration in `html`

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

Actually takes in consideration the line break.

---

The same declaration in `jsx` is the equivalent of writing like this in `html`

```
<button>1</button><button>2</button>
```

[image: Edit bitter-cdn-mlqrr]